# reloading prometheus configuration file

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

In my prometheus configuration file I have specified the target as `localhost:8080`, but after running prometheus I am seeing instance as `localhost:9090`.  What are the steps to be followed after changing the prometheus configuration file?

Comment: prometheus  runs on port 9090. You can kill the prometheus  process and restart the prometheus to reload the configuration. Hope you correctly config the configuration file with port 8080.static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:8080']